# Delegate methods not being called/ChildViewController somehow ending up nil

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, delegates

I'm new to delegation, so I've been looking for answers, and I've looked at [method delegates doesn't get called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738400/method-delegates-doesnt-get-called?rq=1) and [Delegate method not being called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5784850/delegate-method-not-being-called) to see if my answer would be there.  I've also looked at [How do I set up a simple delegate to communicate between two view controllers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6168919/how-do-i-set-up-a-simple-delegate-to-communicate-between-two-view-controllers) for a brief rundown of delegates and have done my best to follow it correctly.  I have been checking my code and I thought I doing it right, but in my debugging, I've learned that I'm clearly not.

What I want to do is reload a tableView from the file "Data.plist" (stored in the Documents directory) when a user segues back to the parent ViewController (the user has just added a new value to the dictionary).  The app loads the new entered correctly upon reopening, so I know that file is being saved correctly.

This is my ParentViewController.h file.

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ChildViewController.h"

@interface ParentViewController : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, ChildViewControllerDelegate>

@end
```

This is my ParentViewController.m file.

```
#import "ParentViewController.h"

@interface ParentViewController () 
@end

@implementation ParentViewController
-(void)addEvent {
    NSLog(@"We are before [self loadNewEvent];");
    [self loadNewEvent];
    NSLog(@"We are after [self loadNewEvent];");
}

-(void)loadNewEvent {
    [self.tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:0 atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionNone animated:YES];
    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:0 withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    //[self.tableView reloadData];//This doesn't seem to do anything but leave the tableview blank when this line is in viewDidLoad and viewWillAppear.
    NSLog(@"WHY IS THIS NOT WORKING?!?!");
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //stuff that loads data initially into tableView
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //cell formatting stuff
    return cell;
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"addEvent"]) {
        [(ChildViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController] setFilePath:filePath];
        ChildViewController *detailViewController = [[ChildViewController alloc] init];
        [detailViewController setDelegate:self];
        //[self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
    }
}
@end
```

This is my ChildViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@protocol ChildViewControllerDelegate;

@interface ChildViewController : UIViewController
@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ChildViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
- (IBAction)dismissAndSave:(id)sender;//in implementation
- (IBAction)dismissCancel:(id)sender;//in implementation
@end

@protocol ChildViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)addEvent;
@end
```

and finally my ChildViewController.m file.

```
#import "ChildViewController.h"
@interface ChildViewController ()
@end

@implementation ChildViewController
- (IBAction)dismissAndSave:(id)sender {
    //perform file-saving operations
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(addEvent)]) {
        [self.delegate addEvent];
    }
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

I've run through and debugged, and the last point where the ChildViewController is not nil is at the `[detailViewController setDelegate:self];` line in the parent's prepareForSegue method.

The reason I knew my delegate methods weren't being called was because `NSLog(@"We are before [self loadNewEvent];");` was not happening.

In addition to the method not being called, when I try to do a `[self.tableView reloadData];` in the `addEvent` delegate method, everything appears blank.

Thank you in advance for your help; you are doing a great service to a student who is teaching himself the ways of iOS programming and Objective-C!

Comment: is it stepping into the if for respondsToSelector?

Comment: I have a feeling your "`self.tableview`" IBOutlet property is not connected.  Heck, I don't even see it declared in your .h "`@interface`" file.

Comment: @Ben Avery, I just added a `NSLog(@"We are inside dismissAndSave respondsToSelector");` line inside of the if statement, and it didn't print out.  That's probably where the issue is. @Michael Dautermann I didn't think I needed one since the information loads on launch without one.  If I need one, how do I set it up without breaking my existing tableView?

Comment: Just before the if respondsToSelector, is delegate = nil?

Comment: delegate is set to 0x0

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment, I believe you need to declare a tableview property in your .h file:

e.g.

```
@property (strong) IBOutlet UITableView *myTableView;
```

which, once connected to the actual table view in your Storyboard or XIB, you can then reference in your .m file like this:

```
[self.myTableView reloadData];
```

Comment: I added both to my code, but I put the `[self.myTableView reloadData];` into my viewWillAppear method but no luck.  Did I put it in the wrong method?

Comment: did you connect your tableview in your storyboard to your new "`myTableView`" outlet in your view controller?

Comment: Yep.  There was a blue box around the whole thing.

Comment: oh and you need to set your data source for your tableview object in your storyboard back to your view controller, so it knows where to draw the data from.

Comment: The ParentViewController is currently the dataSource and delegate, and the myTableView is a "Reference Outlet".  Still doesn't seem to reload the data.  Am I putting the call in the wrong spot or do I have myTableView hooked up to the wrong place?

Comment: Another method you are missing is the *required* datasource one named ["`tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:`"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDataSource/tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:).  Can you implement that?

Comment: I figured the reload issue out.  Thanks!!  I was putting the line in the viewWillAppear method instead of viewDidAppear.  Now I know what the differences are.  However, I still don't have the delegation working, but as long as it refreshes, I'm happy.  It's probably a more standard practice to use delegation though...so I should still find out why that's not working.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're allocating a new view controller, setting its delegate and then don't do anything with it.  It'll get dealloc'd once it is out of scope.

```
[(ChildViewController *)[[segue destinationViewController] topViewController] setFilePath:filePath];
ChildViewController *detailViewController = [[ChildViewController alloc] init];
[detailViewController setDelegate:self];
```

Try something like this...

```
ChildViewController * detailViewController = (id)[segue destinationViewController];
[detailViewController setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: What do I do about the filePath parameter?